# How to reference bytearray in VB.NEt

Tags: vb.net, reference, include, arrays

I'm working on a WebRequest function in VB.NET and following Microsoft's example code.
However I have hit a problem

```
request.ContentLength = byteArray.Length;
```

The issue is that I don't know how to include or reference `byteArray`. 
Do you know which reference to add in order go gain access to byteArray?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I presume you are referring to this MSDN article here:

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/debx8sh9(v=vs.110).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/debx8sh9%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

If you scroll all the way to the bottom you will see that 'byteArray' is just a variable defined like so:

```
        Dim postData As String = "This is a test that posts this string to a Web server."
        Dim byteArray As Byte() = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(postData)
```

Comment: Thank you - feeling stupid - but thank you for the great response